# Generating C# class file from XML Schema

Tags: c#, xml, schema

I want to parse a complex XML schema file and export to a C# file.

Do I need take use `System.XML.Schema` namespace?

Comment: Given that you are parsing XML it would make sense to use that part of the framework but it's by no means mandatory. Go give it a try and if you get stuck then come back, show what you are doing, describe how it's not working and I'm sure you'll get some help.

Comment: Hi Sir Lazarus,

Good day.

I will collect my detail questions/requirements at the comming study days.

Thank you.
Nano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XSD.EXE, and the command will be something like this:

```
XSD.EXE your.xsd /c
```

The generated source has a couple of quirks:

- It generates `[SerializableAttribute]`, `[XmlTypeAttribute]`, `[XmlRootAttribute]`, etc., rather than `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, which may *(not)* be a problem for you.
- It defines child/detail structures using arrays within, rather than generic `List<T>` structures.

I usually have to tweak it fairly heavily (with a few search & replace operations), plus manually handling the lists.  Regardless, it provides a good starting point.

Comment: Hi Sir Mike, Good day. I followed your command from .net 2.0 SDK command line, and i generated my C# file from my XSD file successfully. I am research more about my new C# file.
thank you.
Nano

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) tool. It does have limitations but it is free and likely already on your system.

If you need bigger and costlier guns I'd suggest [Liquid Xml Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Xml-Data-Binder.aspx) or [Altova](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html).

Comment: Thank you sir Typtseven too. I think i could study XSD tool and try to work out my SR.
Appreciated for your resource.
BR!
Nano